# LiteCollection to CSV

Tags: c#, csv, litedb

Apologies for the simplistic question - I'm just a hobbyist programmer.

In C# How do I save the LiteCollection to a CSV file?

I can see from the Documentation (https://www.litedb.org/docs/collections/)  that there is a

```
 'SELECT $ INTO $FILE('customers.csv') FROM Customers'
```

I'm just not sure how or where to use it!

Any help will be appreciated :)

Thanks

(https://www.litedb.org/)

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to get a csv file from a LiteDB collection, without code, is to use the "LiteDB studio" tool released by the team.

https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB.Studio

In the tool you can access to your db file, and run the query you posted before.

Here you can find the export options
https://www.litedb.org/docs/collections/